# Deploying app with Payara throws "Exception during lifecycle processing"

Tags: java, jdbc, jax-rs, payara

I have a simple Java app with JAX-RS and JDBC to manage user requests. The application is deployed with Payara; it builds fine, but for some reason it throws this cryptic error while deploying, and I have literally no idea what could this possibly mean, since it doesn't even point to any file I have written. I have already tried installing this joda time library from Maven, but it still won't deploy. Anyone knows what could this possibly mean?

```
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating :org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:484)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:488)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1474)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1856)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1732)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Error instantiating :org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.createInstance(ServiceLoader.java:315)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.prepareInstance(ServiceLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:215)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.getExtensions(DeploymentImpl.java:476)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:255)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.createInstance(ServiceLoader.java:313)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.joda.time.ReadableInstant not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.resolveTypeForClassAndHierarchy(TypeHelper.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.resolveTypes(TypeHelper.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.extractType(TypeHelper.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.forClass(ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.java:49)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.putConstraints(ConstraintHelper.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.<init>(ConstraintHelper.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:116)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1738)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1675)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1511)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 77 more
```

Thanks in advance for any help